# Passing Ng-disabled Expressions to Elements Inside of a Directive Via Attritbutes

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to pass an expression that  I will use inside of the view of a directive for one of its element's ng-disabled setting like so (simplified for clarity):

```
<my-directive data-when-to-disable="!var1||var2==var3"></my-directive>
```

When declaring myDirective I set its scope like so:

```
scope: {
            whenToDisable: '&'
        }
```

and then in the view of my-directive I have:

```
<div ng-disabled="whenToDisable()"></div>
```

I know many are going to comment on why don't I just put the ng-disabled directly in the parent controller when I use the my-directive element but I cannot because in the real scenario it is based on variables in the child scope that are dynamically changing. This works perfectly if the expression sent in the attribute is checking one variable like so:

```
<my-directive data-when-to-disable="!var1"></my-directive>
```

but when I use something a little more complex:

```
<my-directive data-when-to-disable="!var1||var2==var3"></my-directive>
```

It only goes up until the logical operator ( || ) and ignores/behaves oddly with the rest. I think overall I am missing using this concept of passing expressions through attribute information. I have isolated it down to `var2==var3` and it couldn't handle that so maybe it lies in not being able to use "=="?

I appreciate any input.

UPDATE: I have found out the error is definitely not in using the OR ( || ) logical operator  as using "false || true" disables it as it should I think the problem is definitely in the use of "==". Somehow I am using it wrong.

Comment: if LHS of logical or operator is true it wont evaluate further, i.e true || runFunc() will not run the function since the expression has already evaluated to true. Do you have an example of specific issue that you have?

Comment: What does LHS mean? There is a specific example mentioned in the bottom of the original question in that the element inside of the directive is not interpreting the expression when it contains "==" or "!==" at all. It acts as if nothing is there.

Comment: i.e probably because !var1 is already true/truthy. LHS -> Left Hand Side

Comment: I have replaced the aspect where !var1 is with a flat out false and it still did not interpret "==" or "!==" in the RHS - good train of thought though.

Comment: Turns out the issue is not with || .

Comment: `as using "false || true" disables it` --> `false || true` will disable because ng-disabled will be true, it means you want to disable it. if that is the issue. It means it works as expected as per what you have coded.

Comment: You should simply use `=`, not `&`. And use `ng-disabled="whenToDisable"`

Comment: PSL - Yup we are on the same page - I agree it should disable and it does so || is not the issue. @JBNizet - Doesn't that bind the values? I  need the child element to use the values from its own controller.

Comment: There is the problem: var1, var2 and var3, in the caller of the directive, will always refer to the caller's controller scope. Not to the directive scope. The caller shouldn't even know about variables used by the directive scope. If that's really what you want to do, you should pass the expression with '@', and use $scope.$eval() to evaluate on the directive scope, inside the directive's link function. You should post the complete directive code, show where these variables are defined and what values they have.

Comment: @JBNizet I am going to try what you suggest now - it sounds very logical and most likely a solution! I will report back. Thanks!

Comment: @JBNizet  - That was the main problem I was having as well as something unrelated - can you please post that comment as an answer so I can give you the green check? (in reference to using @ and $scope.$eval())

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When passing expressions using `=`or `&`, the expression is evaluated in the context of the controller scope, not on the directive scope. If you want this expression to be evaluated on the directive isolate scope, pass it as a string, using '@', and use `$scope.$eval()` in the directive to evaluate it.